# PHP: Regex preg_replace_callback to match all numbers in PHP

Tags: php, regex, expression, matching, zero

```
preg_replace_callback( "/[0-9]*/", array( &$this, '_getPHPNumber' ), $code );

private function _getPHPNumber( $matches ) {
    return ( $this->_getHtmlCode( $matches[0], PHP::$Colors['number'] ) );
}

private function _getHtmlCode( $text, $color ) {
    $rows = array_filter( explode( "\n", $text ) );
    $count = count( $rows );
    $output = '';

    for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        $n = ( $count > 1 ? ( $i != $count - 1 ? "\n" : "" ) : "" );
        $output .= "<span style=\"color:{$color};\">{$rows[$i]}</span>{$n}";

    }

    return ( $output );
}
```

The output of the above would look like this:

```
<span style="color:#FF0000;">152</span>
```

It works great, except if the number is a 0, it gets removed from output. The line causing the issue is `$rows = array_filter( explode( "\n", $text ) );` in the `_getHtmlCode`. The exact cause is `array_filter`. If I remove it, my output gets completely broken, but the 0's appear. If I leave it, the 0's get removed.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for array_filter has your answer

> *If no callback is supplied, all*
>   *entries of input equal to FALSE (see*
>   *converting to boolean) will be*
>   *removed.*

And I believe [0 evaluates to FALSE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).

I can't test at the moment but I believe this will work

```
$rows = array_filter( explode( "\n", $text ), 'is_string' );
```